# Add layer to react-leaflet MapContainer after 1st render (dynamically)

Tags: react-leaflet

is it possible to add a layer to react-leaflet v4 dynamically? i.e. after the MapContainer and all its children have rendered.

use case example: user selects a date from a calendar widget to load a specific image to the map e.g. a TileLayer. The problem is that the dates go back years, so I cannot simply preload a  component for each image and just show it if the user selects it.

I am looking for a best practice for doing this in react-leaflet. It is very simple with plain JS and leaflet... But I'm new to react-leaflet and things work a bit differently.

TIA

Comment: In case someone comes across this in future, the simplest way is to create a component:

import { useLeafletContext } from '@react-leaflet/core'
import L from 'leaflet'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

function Square(props) {
  const context = useLeafletContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    const bounds = L.latLng(props.center).toBounds(props.size)
    const square = new L.Rectangle(bounds)
    const container = context.layerContainer || context.map
    container.addLayer(square)

    return () => {
      container.removeLayer(square)
    }
  })

  return null
}

Comment: if you have solved your own question, then put it as solved in the answer field. In this way atleast the rendering of your solution would be more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[extracted from OP's comment]

In case someone comes across this in future, the simplest way is to create a component:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLeafletContext } from '@react-leaflet/core'
import L from 'leaflet'

function Square(props) {
  const context = useLeafletContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    const bounds = L.latLng(props.center).toBounds(props.size)
    const square = new L.Rectangle(bounds)
    const container = context.layerContainer || context.map
    container.addLayer(square)
    return () => {
      container.removeLayer(square)
    }
  })
  return null
}
```